# Postgres to Redshift DMS Geographic Data

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, aws-dms

I am working to set up an AWS DMS replication task to replicate data from Postgres to Redshift.  I set up a proof of concept and everything worked well.  I am almost certain when I initially set everything up it exported geographic data in a (well known text) WKT format.  However after setting everything up in Terraform it now produces data in a KML format.  Redshift does not work with KML formatted geographies. Is there a way to force AWS DMS or postgres to output data in WKT format?